# C++ Linked list issues with strings

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm quite new to C++ and currently trying to insert a phone number and name inside of a linked list that the user can set.I'm wondering where I'm going wrong, I've been watching video after video but everything is about using integers in linked lists and not strings.

So if main was taken out the program shows (0)errors and (0)warnings so I think the problem is in main.

So in main I'm trying to cin nam(which is what I have inside the function part of set_first). I've tried passing it an address but I think I'm just pulling at straws with that.

So the question is: Can anyone point me in the right direction, or let me know how I could put a name and a phone number into a node that a user specifies?

Here's my the programs thus far descending from main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "l_List_1.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    l_List_1 obr;

    std::string nam;
    cout << "name";
    cin >> nam;
    obr.set_first(nam); //I'm trying to give it the nam since that's what I have inside my set_first function.



return 0;
}
```

My header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef L_LIST_1_H
#define L_LIST_1_H


class l_List_1
{
public:
    l_List_1();
    void set_first(std::string nam, int phnum);
    void delete_Node(std::string del_nams, int num_del);
    void display();
    char menu();


private:
    typedef struct node {
        std::string user_Name;
        int user_Phone;
        node* next;
    }* nodeptr;

    nodeptr head;
    nodeptr curr;
    nodeptr tail;
    nodeptr temp;
};

#endif // L_LIST_1_H
```

and my cpp file is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "l_List_1.h"

using namespace std;


l_List_1::l_List_1()
{
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

void l_List_1::set_first(std::string nam, int phnum) {
    nodeptr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->user_Name = nam;
    n->user_Phone = phnum;

    cout << "name";
    cin >> nam;

    if (head != NULL) {
        curr = head;
        while (curr->next != NULL) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
}
    else {
        head = n;
    }
}

void l_List_1::delete_Node(std::string del_nams, int num_del){
    nodeptr delptr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL && curr->user_Name != del_nams && curr->user_Phone != num_del){
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(curr == NULL){
        cout << del_nams << "Was not in the list";
        cout << num_del << "was not in the list";
        delete delptr;
    } else{
        delptr = curr;
        curr = curr-> next;
        temp->next = curr;
        delete delptr;
        cout << "the item" << del_nams << "was deleted";
        cout << "the item" << num_del << "was deleted";
    }
}

void l_List_1::display(){
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL){
        cout << curr->user_Name;
        cout << curr->user_Phone << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's something missing from your question. That would be an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

For starters member function `set_first` is declared with two parameters

```
void set_first(std::string nam, int phnum);
```

However you call it with one argument

```
obr.set_first(nam);
```

In the function itself (and in the second function that deletes nodes) you do not set the tail of the list.

Also it is not clear what these statements do in the function

```
cout << "name";
cin >> nam;
```

You should remove them.

And there is no sense to declare the following data members

```
nodeptr curr;
nodeptr temp;
```

Instead of them you could use local variables in the methods.

Take into account that you should include header `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```

and I do not see that something from the header `<cstdlib>` is used in your program. You may remove the header.